Can I flag suspected AI-generated posts as "Plagiarized content"?
I found a post that I suspect to be generated by ChatGPT or another LLM service.
The available guidance about what to do in such cases suggests to raise an "In need of moderator intervention" flag.
May I raise a "Plagiarized content" flag instead, on the grounds that uncited content, no matter where it comes from, is considered plagiarism on Stack Overflow?
Return to FAQ index

tl;dr
Yes, you can. And your flag should be marked "helpful"1. However, "In need of moderator intervention" is still a better flag choice.

Any content which is not authored by the post owner and not properly referenced is considered plagiarism. The flag is technically correct.
Furthermore, if the post you flag is eligible to retain the reputation accrued so far, only deleting it "as plagiarism" will undo the illegitimate reputation gain.
However this could result in your flag being delayed much more than it could have.
Since the introduction of the plagiarism flag, the moderators UI now has a separate bucket for "Plagiarized content" flag. Flagging suspected AI-generated posts as plagiarism results in a categorization that, in practice, is sub-optimal. Plagiarism cases are slow and cumbersome to handle. As a consequence, the "Plagiarized content" flag bucket is simply looked at less often. If you want your flag to be handled sooner, use an "In need of moderator intervention" flag.
Moderators don't lose anything valuable here because both flags allow for custom flag text where you can explain why you are flagging the post, and in the rare cases where the post reputation needs to be invalidated, the moderator can raise a "Plagiarized content" flag themselves2 and delete the post as such; and the "chat.openai.com" that you'd input as "Link(s) to original content" doesn't really matter at all. We don't care which LLM produced the output.
We look forward to a future — which is still shrouded in the mists of Stack Exchange Inc.'s staffing shortages — where a dedicated AI flag will be implemented.

1: if it's determined that the flag has merit
2: there are userscripts which make this quick and effortless

The full post leads me to the opposite conclusion as your tl;dr. I would rather see the content removed quickly, than worry about "illegitimate reputation gain" - since such posts often get downvoted anyway, and suspension etc. is more interesting to me from the "justice" perspective.

@KarlKnechtel note that the tl;dr says that you can flag, not must flag. Which flag to use is up to the flagger. The purpose of this post is to say that "In need of moderator intervention" is preferred.
